# Tricky where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I don’t know if it’s me being on the back end of a very long day or I’ve got the coders equivalent of writers block but I can’t think of a clean way of doing this.

I have a table that stores a web pages menu structure, and i want a simple stored procedure that will return the relevant menu items based on the session parameters in the web application.

Take the following (simplified) example:

```
--#### Create example table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Page](
    [PageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RequireLogin] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [RequireAdmin] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [HideIfLoggedIn] [bit] NOT NULL
)
GO

--#### Insert Dummy Data
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Page] ON
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Page] ([PageID], [RequireLogin], [RequireAdmin], [HideIfLoggedIn]) VALUES (2, 1, 0, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Page] ([PageID], [RequireLogin], [RequireAdmin], [HideIfLoggedIn]) VALUES (3, 1, 1, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Page] ([PageID], [RequireLogin], [RequireAdmin], [HideIfLoggedIn]) VALUES (4, 0, 0, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Page] ([PageID], [RequireLogin], [RequireAdmin], [HideIfLoggedIn]) VALUES (5, 0, 0, 0)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Page] OFF

--#### Create menu procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetSubMenu
    @ParentID INT ,
    @IsLoggedIn BIT ,
    @IsAdmin BIT
AS 
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT  PageID ,
                RequireLogin ,
                RequireAdmin ,
                HideIfLoggedIn
        FROM    tbl_Page
        WHERE ????????????
    END
GO
```

For the given example data, the following needs to be true:

1. Page ID 2 should only be listed if `@IsLoggedIn = 1`
2. Page ID 3 should only be listed if `@IsLoggedIn = 1` **AND** `@IsAdmin = 1`
3. Page ID 4 should be listed all the time **UNLESS** `@IsLoggedIn = 1` (there may well be pages that require a logged in user (and even an admin user) but still need hiding too - this is the bit where my brain explodes...)
4. Page ID 5 should be visible all the time regardless if the user is logged in or not and if they are an admin or not as it does not require login and it isnt hidden for logged in users

Comment: can you give sample records in tabular format?

Comment: I personally prefer the format you have given it in. Makes setting up a SQL Fiddle easier.

Comment: Regarding #3, if a page has both `RequireLogin` and `HideIfLoggedIn` set, would that mean it should be excluded regardless of the value of `@IsLoggedIn`? Or does one preference take precedence over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select PageID,
  RequireLogin,
  RequireAdmin,
  HideIfLoggedIn
from tbl_Page
where (HideIfLoggedIn <> @IsLoggedIn)
  and (RequireLogin = 0 or @IsLoggedIn = 1)
  and (RequireAdmin = 0 or @IsAdmin = 1)
```

Works for me.

Edit after comment:

```
select PageID,
  RequireLogin,
  RequireAdmin,
  HideIfLoggedIn
from tbl_Page
where ((HideIfLoggedIn <> @IsLoggedIn)
  and (RequireLogin = 0 or @IsLoggedIn = 1)
  and (RequireAdmin = 0 or @IsAdmin = 1))
  or (RequireLogin = 0 and RequireAdmin = 0 and HideIfLoggedIn = 0)
```

I've updated the query to catch your last requirement, and updated the following SQL Fiddles:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/642ad/17) for `@IsLoggedIn = 1, IsAdmin = 0` - `PageID` *2,5* displayed.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/642ad/16) for `@IsLoggedIn = 1, IsAdmin = 1` - `PageID` *2,3,5* displayed.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/642ad/15) for `@IsLoggedIn = 0, IsAdmin = 1` - `PageID` *4,5* displayed.

Comment: Very close – well done, however i missed the most common occurrence from my example, when RequireLogin = 0 AND RequireAdmin = 0 AND HideIfLoggedIn = 0 this indicates something that should be visible to anyone - logged in or not, I need to adjust your answer to take this into account too. – I’ve revised my question to include this scenario (Page ID 5) – id be interested to see how you’d tackle this :)

Comment: OK, updated; since this new case doesn't really match the rest of the logic (particularly *@IsLoggedIn*), I think the easiest thing to do is to add one last check at the end to capture the particular combination. All the updated examples now work; let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  PageID ,
            RequireLogin ,
            RequireAdmin ,
            HideIfLoggedIn
    FROM    tbl_Page
    WHERE 
   (@IsLoggedIn = 1 AND [HideIfLoggedIn] = 0) 
   AND [RequireLogin] = @IsLoggedIn
   AND [RequireAdmin] = @IsAdmin
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this has better readability when the where clause is structured around the negative...

```
SELECT 
    PageID,
    RequireLogin,
    RequireAdmin,
    HideIfLoggedIn
FROM 
    tbl_Page
WHERE 
    NOT
    (
       (HideIfLoggedIn = 1 AND @IsLoggedIn = 1)
       OR (RequireLogin = 1 AND @IsLoggedIn = 0)
       OR (RequireAdmin = 1 AND @IsAdmin = 0)
    )
```